# for(;;) vs. for(:) in Objective-C Performance and Practice

Tags: objective-c

Is there any different between `for(;;)` and `for(:)` in terms of performance in Objective-C? And what are good practices to use `for(;;)` or `for(:)`?

Comment: Two semicolons make a colon, so they are exactly equivalent.

Comment: Hahaha good point.I believe there may be some difference in performance like any other languages such as Javascript and C#.

Comment: This would be so easy to just build a test case for each loop style and do some profiling runs.

Comment: How does the performance of an infinite loop matter?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I didn't mean infinite loops. I meant using for statements with either semicolons and colons.

Comment: This question belongs on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll assume that in each case you are enumerating a collection of objects, as only the C `for(;;)` form allows enumeration of primitive types. The `for(in)` construction uses a protocol called `NSFastEnumeration` to fill a buffer with objects to use in future iterations, and uses a cursor to track which object it's got up to. That makes it faster than:

```
NSEnumerator *e = [collection objectEnumerator];
while (id o = [e nextObject]) {
  //...
}
```

which requires one message-send per iteration, and it's faster than:

```
for (NSInteger i=0; i < [collection count]; i++) {
  id o = [collection objectAtIndex: i];
  //...
}
```

which also requires one message-send per iteration[*]. The `for(in)` construct only requires a message send every time the buffer runs dry, which might be once every 8 iterations or so.

Notice that there's also block-based looping with `[collection enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id obj, int idx, BOOL *stop){/*...*/}];` which has different properties again. Particularly the version of this construction that takes options can be told to execute the blocks concurrently.

[*]Observant readers will notice that this actually requires *two* message sends per iteration, as the termination condition will be evaluated every time through; however it's so easy to reduce that to one message send that we'll treat it as one for this discussion.